# how to color a certain part of a line

Tags: c#, text, colors, console

For example if I type the word *Hello*, I want the *H* to be red and *O* to be blue, while *ELL* is yellow.

How do I do this?

When I use the code `System.ForegroundColor = Consolecode.Red` all of the text becomes red.

Answer (score 4):

> When i use the code System.ForegroundColor = Consolecode.Red all of the text becomes red

You can output `"Hello"` part by part, using `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write("H");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.Write("e");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.Write("llo");
```